# Using VueJS via CDN within an Angular 1.x application – @mousemove / v-on:mousemove not working

Tags: angularjs, vue.js

As the title states, I’m unable to use @mousemove / v-on:mousemove or event listeners with the v-on directive.

So for instance this will not work:

`<div v-on:click="clickHandler">`

Mustache syntax for text interpolation is also not understood. e.g.

`<p>{{ variable }}</p>`

I have a very minimal knowledge of Angular – is there a simple way to disable it within an html element so that VueJS will work? Was aware of `ng-non-bindable` but this doesn’t work so am not sure I’ve correctly understood it’s use.

Comment: Are you using both angularjs and vue.js in the same project?  Can you even do that?

Comment: https://github.com/ngVue/ngVue